# Only my last condition is respected with reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hello I tried to put this condition in my data: `data={filtersMenu && matchData && showGood ? matchData : matchData.filter((i) => i.state !== "Good")}`

but only this part is working (displaying data where state !==Good)
`matchData && showGood ? matchData : matchData.filter((i) => i.state !== "Good")`

or if I do: `data={filtersMenu}`  it works (allow me to filter via my dropdowns) my data content in my table.

So putting both conditions should allow me to display content where my `state!==Good` **and** (filtersMenu && matchData).

MenuDisplay component:

```
export default function MenuDisplay() {
  const { menuId } = useParams();
  const [menus, setMenus] = useState([]);      
  const [taste, setTaste] = useState([
    { label: "Good", value: "Good", name: "Good", selected: false },
    { label: "Medium", value: "Medium", name: "Medium", selected: false },
    { label: "Bad", value: "Bad", name: "Bad", selected: false }
  ]);
  ...    
  useEffect(() => {
    myapi.menusFunction(parseInt(menuId))
        .then(res => {
            const menus = res.data.menus;
            setMenus([
                ...menus.filter((i) => i.state === "Good"),
                ...menus.filter((i) => i.state !== "Good")
            ])
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}, [menuId]);
 
  const buttonMode = Object.values(selected).some((isSelected) => isSelected)
    ? "apply"
    : "cancel";    
  
  const matchData = (
    match.filter(({ _id }) => {
    return !hidden[_id];
  });
     
  const data = [
    ... 
    {
      Header: "Show",
      accessor: (row) => (
        <Toggle
          value={selected[row._id]}
          onChange={rowSelectHandler(row._id)}
        />
      )
    }
  ];

  const reset = (list) =>
        list.map((v) => ({
            ...v,
            selected: false
        }));

    const cancel = () => {       
        setTaste(reset(taste))
        ...
    };

    const filtersMenu = matchData.filter((menu) => {    
      const allTaste = taste.every(i => i.selected === false)
      const selTaste = (taste.filter((e) => e.selected)).map(({ value }) => value);
      const allTasteSel = selTaste.indexOf(menu.taste) >= 0
      ...
      return allTasteSel && ...
  });

  return (
    <div>
      ...        
      <Table
        data={filtersMenu && matchData && showGood ? matchData : matchData.filter((i) => i.state !== "Good")}      
        columns={data}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you create a codesanbox example?

Comment: Could you also tell what is expected output considering some example input

Comment: Please add the whole code linked in any way with this module, either here or on sandbox or somewhere else. Because the behavior of this code is totally unexpected without knowing the whole code.

Comment: You can replace `selTaste.indexOf(menu.taste) >= 0` with `selTaste.includes(menu.taste)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this statement is logically wrong:

```
filtersMenu && matchData && showGood ? matchData : matchData.filter((i) => i.state !== "Good")
```

Since when, `filtersMenu && matchData && showGood` is true, you want to show only the items which are filtered by your dropdown and are good, then, it should be like this:

```
filtersMenu && matchData && showGood ? filtersMenu.filter((i) => i.state === 'Good') : matchData
```

If the condition fails, you can either return `matchData` or `filtersMenu`, depending on your usecase.

Comment: With `filtersMenu && matchData && showGood ? filtersMenu.filter((i) => i.state === 'Good') : matchData`, my filters don't apply when I select my options from my dropdowns. And all datta where `state===Good` are displayed.  I just want to display only data where `state!==Good` **and** my (`filtersMenu` && `matchData`)

Comment: Can you create a working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/new?file=/src/App.js? The dropdown and other things are missing. Do share the new link in the question

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets `{}` like below

```js
columns=filtersMenu && matchData && showGood ? matchData : matchData.filter((i) => i.state !== "Good")
```

i also think your logic is wrong

Try like this

```js
columns=filtersMenu && matchData && showGood ?  matchData.filter((i) => i.state !== "Good" : matchData)
```

Answer (score 0):

is it just parenthesis around (filtersMenu && matchData && showGood) ? :

```
data={ ( filtersMenu && matchData && showGood ) ? matchData : matchData.filter((i) => i.state !== "Good") }
```